# PHP / DOM : parse HTML to extract data based on class

Tags: php, dom

I have this HTML

```
<div class="news">
    <h3 class="border-bottom">Title 2</h3>
    <p class="mt-0 ml-1">2023-04-01</p>
    <img src="20230401.jpg" class="w-50 float-right ml-2">
    <p class="lead"><p>Description 2</p></p>
    <a href="https://.../news/245" class="btn btn-secondary">Read more</a>
</div>
<div class="news">
    <h3 class="border-bottom">Title 1</h3>
    <p class="mt-0 ml-1">2023-03-31</p>
    <img src="20230331.jpg" class="w-50 float-right ml-2">
    <p class="lead"><p>Description 1</p></p>
    <a href="https://.../news/244" class="btn btn-secondary">Read more</a>
</div>
```

I want to extract the Title and Date for each item. I have tries this

```
$class = "news";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$a = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divs = $a->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");

foreach ($divs as $link) {
    print_r($link->nodeValue);
}
```

But it shows:

> Title 2
>
> 2023-04-01
>
> Description 2
>
> Read more
>
> Title 1
>
> 2023-03-31
>
> Description 1
>
> Read more

I am stuck and can't figure out how to extract this

Comment: Your XPath expression looks good to me (although you could tighten it using 'div' instead of '*').  How many divs is it matching?

Comment: Note that nodeValue returns all the text content within that element (including within child elements).  If you want to pick out specifically the title and date you'll need to query further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your sample is invalid (it contains nested `<p>`s). Assuming you fix that, I would try something like this:

```
$qu = "//div[contains(@class,'{$class}')]";
$divs = $a->query($qu);
foreach ($divs as $div)
{   
    $targets = $a->query('.//h3 | p[1]',$div);
    echo($targets[0]->textContent ." ".$targets[1]->textContent."\r\n");
};
```

Output, based on your fixed sample html:

```
Title 2 2023-04-01
Title 1 2023-03-31
```

EDIT:

To get the link as well, the for loop should be changed to:

```
{   
    $targets = $a->query('.//h3 | p[1] | a/@href',$div);
    echo($targets[0]->textContent ." ".$targets[1]->textContent." ".$targets[2]->textContent."\r\n");
};
```

The output should now be:

```
Title 2 2023-04-01 https://.../news/245
Title 1 2023-03-31 https://.../news/244
```

Comment: Thank you! And if I want to retrieve the link? a->textContent gives "Read more" but not the link

Comment: @Jibeji Indeed, you are now trying to retrieve an attribute value, not the text content of a node. The syntax is different. See edit for update.